# Where is Xcode located on the hard drive?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos

I have looked everywhere but couldn't find it anywhere. I installed it successfully but I don't know where it is installed. Shouldn't it show up at the "start menu"?

I know how to use pc, but this is my new mac mini and I searched the web for tutorials and basic info which doesn't seem to be easily found.

Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Xcode and the rest of the Apple Developer tools get installed to **/Developer**

Simply open the Finder (Mac face in bottom left of the Dock) and Choose:

> Macintosh HD/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But how do I go there? When you I go mac hd > applications, I don't see xcode there. It's really frustrating.

Comment: I didn't say Mac HD > Applications. I said Mac HD / Developer / Applications. I added a pic to make it more clear.

Comment: Thank you, I posted my first comment before you added more info.

Answer (score 5):

Use Spotlight, and just type `xcode`. You will see it.

Comment: I never use anything else to launch apps anymore... spotlight is THE thing

Answer (score 2):

I think it installs somewhere under /Developer or something like that...
But you can always use Spotlight to find and start it:

Press Command-Key (the one next to Space with the funny sign) + Space and type xcode. Press enter and it should start.

Comment: Thank you. Is the command key, windows key on pc keyboard? I don't have a mac keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

You might also consider installing Quicksilver, LaunchBar, or Butler — all three are quick-launchers which allow you to press something like Ctrl-Space and type an abbreviation of the app name, so entering 'xc' will get you XCode.

It's the same as you're getting with Spotlight, but you can do other useful things that Spotlight doesn't make so easy: if you've entered an abbreviation for a document, for example, you can hit Tab and enter the abbreviation for the app you want to open it with.

Quicksilver and Butler are free; LaunchBar costs money. Butler has the best icon, IMHO :)

Unfortunately I can't give you direct links as my reputation's too low and I'm not allowed more than one — but you can find them all by searching at http://macupdate.com…

Comment: QuickSilver doesn't index /Developer by default. It's quite a pain to set this up if you're not familiar with the folders in the first place.

Comment: QuickSilver: http://www.blacktree.com/
Butler: http://www.manytricks.com/butler/
LaunchBar: http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html

and +1 to help with the rep ;-)

Comment: To get QuickSilver to index Xcode, go to "Catalog" in Quicksilver and check the "Find All Applications"